# npm can't resolve babel_loader when running React with Django

Tags: django, reactjs, npm, webpack

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/drf/) for integration React with Django. I have gone through all the steps, but when I run `npm run dev`, I get this error:

```
> AttractoraProject@1.0.0 dev /Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/AttractoraProject
> webpack --mode development ./Attractora/frontend/src/index.js --output ./Attractora/frontend/static/frontend/main.js


Insufficient number of arguments or no entry found.
Alternatively, run 'webpack(-cli) --help' for usage info.

Hash: cf46d3c1f598793a6a6e
Version: webpack 4.40.2
Time: 111ms

Built at: 09/18/2019 2:05:08 PM

ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'babel_loader' in '/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/AttractoraPro
ject'
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! AttractoraProject@1.0.0 dev: `webpack --mode development ./Attractora/frontend/src/index.js --output ./Attractora/
frontend/static/frontend/main.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the AttractoraProject@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/hugovillalobos/.npm/_logs/2019-09-18T19_05_08_809Z-debug.log
```

I ran this command to install babel, so I don't know what I am missing:

```
npm i @babel/core babel-loader @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react babel-plugin-transform-class-properties --save-dev
```

Comment: Is there a folder named `node_modules` on this directory `/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/AttractoraProject`?

Comment: Yes @ToanQuocHo, such folder exists in that position

Comment: Looks like there's a typo in your config or import:  `babel_loader` should be `babel-loader`

Comment: Could you please provide your `webpack.config.js` content?

Comment: That was it, @j3py!!! Is already working, thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @HuLuViCa you're welcome :)